# Disable UISlider from sliding, but still allow it to receive UIControlEventTouchDown

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

Is there a way to disable a `UISlider` from sliding, but to get its `UIControlEventTouchDown` to fire? One way it could be done I believe is to set the slider start value the same as the end value, but I'd like to avoid doing that. Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest setting userInteractionEnabled = NO for your UISlider, and adding an invisible button to handle the TouchDown

```
UIButton *btnSlider = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnSlider.frame = CGRectMake(slider.frame.origin.x, slider.frame.origin.y,         slider.frame.size.width, slider.frame.size.height);
[btnSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
btnSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[myView addSubview:btnSlider];
```

Then based on whatever condition you want to make the slider enabled, you can enable it and disable the button.

Comment: Hello there what is "myView" ? UIslider ?

Comment: myView is whichever view the UISlider has been added to.